# How can I update or delete records of hive table from spark , with out loading entire table in to dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, hivecontext, spark-hive

I have a hive orc table with around 2 million records , currently to update or delete I am loading entire table in to a dataframe and then update and save as new dataframe and saving this by Overwrite mode(below is command),so to update single record do I need to load and process entire table data??

I'm unable to do objHiveContext.sql("update myTable set columnName='' ") 
I'm using Spark 1.4.1, Hive 1.2.1

`myData.write.format("orc").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("myTable")`  where myData is updated dataframe.

How can I get rid of loading entire 2-3 million records just to update a single record of hive table .

Comment: AFAIK you cannot. Spark is designed for large scale analytics not to perform fine grade changes on external data sources.

Comment: Thank you!, how can we dispose(delete) a dataframe after its use? I'm getting outOfMemoryException, how can I increase heap size?